# How to put bull inside css circle

Tags: html, css, radio-button, vertical-alignment

I need to create a line with a few circles inside and with a dot inside these circles.. They should look like radio buttons - how can I align the dot vertically?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy0keb4v/)

HTML

```
<div class="round" id="round-vertically">
                <div class="circle img1" id="circle-star"><span>&bull;</span></div>
                <div class="circle-line"></div>
                <div class="circle img2" id="circle-key"><span>&bull;</span></div>
                <div class="circle-line"></div>
                <div class="circle img3" id="circle-cursor"><span>&bull;</span></div>
                <div class="circle-line"></div>
                <div class="circle img4" id="circle-mobile"><span>&bull;</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use characters, create it by css:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="eye"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.eye{
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 2em; height: 2em;
}
.eye::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOaBKg

Comment: Looks fantastic :) thank you very much - I think I'll use this solution in future many times ;)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```
.circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px #d3d4de solid;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.circle-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #d3d4de;
  height: 191px;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px #d3d4de solid;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#round-vertically {
  padding-top: 95px;
}
#round-vertically SPAN {
  color: #d3d4de;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="round" id="round-vertically">

  <div class="circle img1" id="circle-star"><span>&bull;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-line"></div>
  <div class="circle img2" id="circle-key"><span>&bull;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-line"></div>
  <div class="circle img3" id="circle-cursor"><span>&bull;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-line"></div>
  <div class="circle img4" id="circle-mobile"><span>&bull;</span>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is by using **translate** css property

```
#round-vertically   SPAN {
color: #d3d4de;
font-size:30px;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-size: 30px;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy0keb4v/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zy0keb4v/2/)

```
.circle {  
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border:1px #d3d4de solid;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;

}
#round-vertically   SPAN {
  color: #d3d4de;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` in class 'circle'. Use `line-height` property `line-height: 50%`. See below snippet:

```css
.circle-line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #d3d4de;
  height: 191px;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {  
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border:1px #d3d4de solid;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#round-vertically {
  padding-top:95px;

}
#round-vertically SPAN {
  color: #d3d4de;

  font-size:30px;
  line-height: 50%
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="round" id="round-vertically">

     <div class="circle img1" id="circle-star"><span>&bull;</span></div>
     <div class="circle-line"></div>
     <div class="circle img2" id="circle-key"><span>&bull;</span></div>
     <div class="circle-line"></div>
     <div class="circle img3" id="circle-cursor"><span>&bull;</span></div>
     <div class="circle-line"></div>
     <div class="circle img4" id="circle-mobile"><span>&bull;</span></div>
     

    </div>
```